# Typescript variadic tuple inference in interfaces?

Tags: typescript, tuples, variadic

Interface:

```
interface D<T extends any[]> {
    a: T
    b: (p: [...T]) => any
}
```

Example implementation:

```
const d: D = {
    a: [1, 2, 'hello'],
    b: (p) => {
        console.log(p[0])
    }
}
```

How can I make typescript infer `d.b`'s first parameter type from `d.a`?

```
// I would like d's type in the example to be inferred as:
{
    a: [number, number, string],
    b: (p: [number, number, string]) => void
}
```

I'm getting error

```
Generic type D<T> requires 1 argument(s).
```

**Note: I need `D.a` to generalize to any tuple, `[number, number, string]` is just an example.**

Edit:

I would like `p` to be a tuple stricty typed as `[number, number, string]`. So `p[0]`, `p[1]` is strictly `number`, `p[2]` is strictly `string`, and accessing `p[3]` should error.

Comment: AFAIK, you can only get TS to infer an array of the union of the types of values in your data `(number | string)[]` OR the literal values `readonly [1, 2, 'hello']` by providing it as `[1, 2, 'hello'] as const`. I don't think TS will ever infer a tuple of `[number, number, string]` for the value provided in your example without some kind of extra assertion/hint. See https://tsplay.dev/WJ4lRN

Comment: Here's an example: https://tsplay.dev/wjkqkN If you'd like to see this written up as an answer, let me know.

Comment: Why do you  have `a` as type `T[]` when `T` is already an array type? You want an array of arrays?  If not, then maybe it should just be `T` or even `[...T]`.  Anyway, does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WP73km) meet your needs?  You need a helper function (as @jsejcksn shows also) to get type inference.  Also, I would think you should use either just `T` or just `[...T]` in your `D` declaration, and you definitely want `[...T]` in the helper function if you'd like the compiler to infer a tuple type.  If that approach works I can write it up; otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: Ah thanks for pointing that out. `a` should just be type `T`. I cannot use any helper functions for my situation.

Comment: "I cannot use any helper functions for my situation". If that's really true then what you want is impossible; there is no specific type `D` corresponding to the infinite union of `D<T>` for all possible `T`. TypeScript does not have direct support existentially quantified generics, which is what you would need; something like (the invalid TS) `interface D<exists T extends any[]> {  a: T, b: (p: [...T]) => any }`.  There are ways to encode such things, but they require some indirection like a helper function shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/w24ljm).

Comment: If this turns out to be impossible, what are you going to do? I'm trying to figure out what sort of answer to post here.  Anyway, if you have a constraint (e.g., "no helper functions, I need a specific type `D` that works the way I'm asking for") then you should probably [edit] the question to include it explicitly (comment chains aren't really part of the question proper).  And maybe fix `T[]` while you're at it.  Finally, if you reply to this comment, please mention me via @jcalz, because otherwise I am not necessarily going to be alerted.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like -

```
// Array with string or number values
type A = Array<number | string>

// D is a generic interface which expects an argument
interface D<T> {
    a: T
    b: (p: T) => any
}

const d: D<A> = {
    a: [1, 2, 'hello'],
    b: (p) => {
        console.log(p);
    }
};
```

If you want to have a fixed Array type as per your question, you can use -

```
type A = [number, number, string];
```

Comment: I would like `p[0]`, `p[1]` to strictly be `number`, `p[2]` to strictly be `string`, and accessing `p[3]` to error.

Comment: @Legend123 
use the below method that 'dhaker' metioned `type A = [number, number, string]`;

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear but that's not the point. I need `D.a` to to generalize to any tuple. It can't be constrained to `[number, number, string]`.

Comment: @Legend123 Can you please add some code snippet where you are trying to use it?

Comment: Why do you need code snippets? The real use case is proprietary. Hopefully the explanation above is clear. If not would appreciate advice on how to clarify.

Comment: @Legend123 Many questions on this site (maybe most?) can be classified such that the asker needs to solve a problem, but they don't know enough about the underlying nature of the problem or code interaction, so the question that ends up being asked is not really one that represents the problem, but rather seeks a solution to one route that the asker thinks will solve it. And in many of those cases, that route is not the optimal one.

Comment: @Legend123 So by showing what this type is actually used for, you are demonstrating the actual problem that you need to solve.